# sed weirdness, unmatched {

Tags: command-line, sed

I'm trying to use the r (read command to append the contents of data2 to data.
I want to append the contents after the line containing 'two'. 
I want to delete the line containing 'two'.

But I've hit a brick wall. It feels like a bug, but perhaps it's just my own stupidity.

Ok this command works.

```
% sed -r '/two/ r /tmp/data2' <  /tmp/data
one
two
five
six
seven
three
four
```

Sed seems a little finiky about spaces.. Not obvious why, but I'll live with it.

```
% sed -r '/two/ r /tmp/data2  ' <  /tmp/data
one
two
three
four
```

My goal is to run a (d) delete after the read command to remove the original line.
This is as far as I get.

```
% sed -r '/two/{ r /tmp/data2}' <  /tmp/data
sed: -e expression #1, char 0: unmatched `{'
```

I'm pretty sure that '{' is being matched, it's not the longest command in the world.

What I actually want to run...

```
% sed -r '/two/{ r /tmp/data2; d }' <  /tmp/data
```

The system is Ubuntu 12. GNU SED.

Comment: Are the curly braces ({}) intended to be literal strings?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`r /file/path` must not have anything after it on its line.

You may find this site helpful as a [Command Summary for sed](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/sedawk/appa_03.htm)

```
echo 'one
two
five
six
seven
three
four' >inputfile

echo 'contents of readfile' >readfile

sed  '/two/{r readfile
         d}' inputfile
```

Note: You can utilize the shell to *parameterize* sed, by using "double quotes". They enable shell variable expansion. `r` takes all spaces literally... so don't quote the filename, and don't have any trailing whitespace (whitespace between `r` and `/file/path` is ok).

```
rfile='/tmp/readfile with   multiple spaces in name'
sed  "/two/{r $rfile
       d}" inputfile
```

*output*

```
one
contents of readfile
five
six
seven
three
four
```

On a side note: There is really no value using `<` for your input file. Use sed's input file parameter (it keeps things simpler).

Comment: Thanks, shame it has to be on it's own line, I was really hoping to get it down to a single line. I was trying stuff like {r $rfile;d} but to no avail.

Comment: I know what you mean about not being able to keep it on the same line, but you can still use it at the command line. just press *Enter* after `r /file/path` to continue the command on the next line... It continues because of the quotes... (most one-liners aren't really one command, but this `sed` is.. You can put a sizeable C program onto one *long* line, but that doesn't make it a *"one-liner"* (to me).

Comment: ;-) I know, it's an obsession...

Comment: My original plan was to embed it inside something like this...
for i in $( print -C1 ./**/pom.xml(:a:h) );; do cd $i; <SED SUBSTITUTION> ; done

Comment: Here is the one-liner (for those who *must* :)... `sed -f <(sed 's/\\n/\n/'<<<"/two/{r $rfile\nd}") inputfile` .. If you like it, give me an upvote :)

Comment: Dude, I can't ( my rep is too low ), but I did mark you as the correct answer.

Comment: ha ha, that command is a thing of beauty!

Answer (score 6):

Break it with multiple '-e' flags, one for each line

```
% sed -e '/two/{ r /tmp/data2' -e 'd}' <  /tmp/data
```